# Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'friendship.status' in 'where clause'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[ArgumentError: Unknown key: :conditions. Valid keys are: :class_name, :class, :foreign_key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31488202/argumenterror-unknown-key-conditions-valid-keys-are-class-name-class-f)

First of all, there is a question, which is almost similar to mine, but I cannot make it work for my code. So, I decided to ask separately.

This is where I get error:

```
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends,
           :through => :friendships,
           :conditions => "status = 'accepted'",
           :order => :screen_name
  has_many :requested_friends,
           :through => :friendships,
           :source => :friend,
           :conditions => "status = 'requested'",
           :order => :created_at
  has_many :pending_friends,
           :through => :friendships,
           :source => :friend,
           :conditions => "status = 'pending'",
           :order => :created_at
```

I don't know if I should share some other of my codes to help you to understand. If you need some other parts, I can also paste them.

This is the full error:

```
Unknown key: :conditions. Valid keys are: :class_name, :class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table, :foreign_type
```

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I fixed the problem:

```
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, -> { where(friendship: {status: 'accepted'}).order('created_at') }, :through => :friendships
  has_many :requested_friends, -> { where(friendship: {status: 'requested'}).order('created_at') }, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend
  has_many :pending_friends, -> { where(friendship: {status: 'pending'}).order('created_at') }, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend
```

This is the error I am getting now:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'friendship.status' in 'where clause': SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` INNER JOIN `friendships` ON `users`.`id` = `friendships`.`friend_id` WHERE `friendships`.`user_id` = 6 AND `friendship`.`status` = 'requested' AND `users`.`id` = 8 LIMIT 1
```

This is where error occurs:

```
  def accept # accept_request
    if @user.requested_friends.include?(@friend)
      Friendship.accept_request(@user, @friend)
    end
    redirect_to profile_path(params[:id])
  end
```

Specifically here:

```
if @user.requested_friends.include?(@friend)
```

accept_request:

```
  def self.accept_request(user, friend)
    transaction do
      accept_one_side(user, friend)
      accept_one_side(friend, user)
    end
  end
```

accept_one_side:

```
  private
  def self.accept_one_side(user, friend)
    request = find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user, friend)
    request.status = 'accepted'
    request.save!
  end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of conditions in has\_many Rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307874/what-is-the-equivalent-of-conditions-in-has-many-rails-4)

Comment: According to the link you gave me, I fixed the problem. But now i am getting some other error.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to call a column from an associated model, which requires a join. Can you post the code where the error is occurring?

Comment: @RyanK probably error is in has_many but still cannot figure out

Comment: What you need is a [join](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins). Probably something like: `joins(:friendships).where(friendship: {status: 'accepted'}}`. Notice the singular friendship in the where clause.

Comment: Cool. Answer your own question since you fixed it. Might help someone else later.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Fixed**

Problem was in has_many.

This is the correct version:

```
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, -> { where(friendships: {status: 'accepted'}).order('created_at') }, :through => :friendships
  has_many :requested_friends, -> { where(friendships: {status: 'requested'}).order('created_at') }, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend
  has_many :pending_friends, -> { where(friendships: {status: 'pending'}).order('created_at') }, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend
```

It may look like same code above but its not.

Because in first code, I wrote: "where(friendship:" but it supposed to be: "where(friendships:" So, I forgot to put 's'